# SharePoint Calendar Overlay in Outlook

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

I love the colored tabs on the right hand side of the SP calendar that represent the different views but when I connect to outlook I dont have the option to keep these tabs. Any ideas on how to get these colored tabs in Outlook?

Comment: Do you mean the objects ("tabs") listed under "Calendars in View"?

Comment: I created a overlay calendar and on the right hand side where the quick launch bar is I have a color coded list of calendars in view. I can click on any of these tabs and it will take me to the calendar. My concern is when I connect to outlook it does not provide me with this list on the right hand side. So I guess my question is is there some kind feature I can enable to activate this or does this need to be coded in outlook to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though the issue you are having is that you have several overlayed calendars and, in SharePoint, on the side of the calendars are tabs to show the events of each respective calendar (see image below)

[image]

If you are looking to show these in Outlook, then it *can* be done, but not well. The tabs indicate individual calendars and if you want them in Outlook, you will unfortunately need to sync each overlayed calendar (not just the main one). On the plus side, once in Outlook you can still overlay them all with your Outlook calendar.

Hope this helps (and I interpretted the issue correctly).

Comment: I created the tabs to replicate the ones in SharePoint but there is no option to synch each overlayed calendar and when I connect to outlook for a individual calendar it brings over the whole overlayed calendar.

Comment: So you're saying the synced calendar in Outlook shows the events of all overlaid calendars, but not the "tabs"? If so, I don't know how you did that but would love to know. As I understand it, you need to individually sync each overlaid SP calendar in the view to Outlook, because there is no way to roll them all into a single synced calendar. If the full calendar (including all the overlaid ones) is syncing to Outlook, then either all of the events are on the main calendar and should be spread out to each of the overlaid calendars or you need to only sync the overlaid calendars individually.